# cannot access mysql server under some circumstances

Tags: mysql

Here's my situation:

- I have on my server mysqld running.
- telnet localhost 3306 gives access
- telnet 127.0.0.1 3306 gives access
- telnet my_host_name 3306 doesn't give access
- telnet ip_of_my_host_name 3306 doesn't give access
- I checked the port: 3306 is open.  My Firewall doesn't block this port

In the mysql logfile I have a message concerning the log sequence which is "in the future".

Is there a relationship between the problem and this message ?

My database uses Innodb.

Comment: Do you have "bind_address 127.0.0.1" in your my.cnf ?

Comment: Sorry:I forgot these basic information ... I run on windows server 2003, mysql version 5.2
bind ... doesn't exist in my.ini
skip-networking doesn't exist in my.ini

Answer (score 1):

Your problem seems to be something related to the binding address of the mysql daemon.

You can have a look [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/139323/mysql-bind-to-more-than-one-ip-address) to get additional information about binding to several addresses (*localhost* and the *public IP* address).

Answer (score 0):

Check https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-networking.

Many distributions have this setting as default.  In your my.cnf, look for:

```
skip-networking
```

and comment that line out.

Comment: Since OP can connect via localhost and 127.0.0.1, `skip-networking` is not the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If you just installed MySQL, remote access is disabled by default. If that's the case, you need to edit the configuration to allow it and restart mysqld. There are several instruction sets on how to do this, [such as this one](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html).

Comment: In this case, bind to any IP: bind-address = 0.0.0.0, then telnet your public IP, port 3306 to verify if the mysqld server is listening as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Since you can connect to localhost, we know that you have the bind-address setting configured.

Look in your my.cnf (or my.ini) file for the following line:

```
bind-address = 127.0.0.1
```

The above line lets you connect ONLY to the local address. MySQL binds itself to the loopback IP, and nothing else.

To be able to connect to all IP addresses on the machine (bind to all addresses), including the local address, change the configuration to the following:

```
bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Alternatively, since `0.0.0.0` is the default, you can comment it out like so:

```
#bind-address = 0.0.0.0
```

Then restart MySQL server.

Your error message is unrelated to this issue.

Comment: This line doesn't exist in my.ini

Comment: Search your computer for all my.ini and my.cnf and startup command line options. If `bind-address` is not the issue, then this is not a MySQL question. The problem lies elsewhere.

Comment: mysqld is starting with a path to a my.ini file.
the problem is the "elsewhere" !